# identifier token keyword antlr parser

Tags: parsing, antlr, token, keyword, identifier

How to handle the case where the token 'for' is used in two different situations in the language to parse? Such as statement and as a "parameter" as the following example:

```
echo for print example
for i in {0..10..2}
  do
     echo "Welcome $i times"
 done
```

Output:

```
for print example
Welcome 0 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 8 times
Welcome 10 times
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is "for" just something to be printed in the first example, or does it also have a meaning?

Comment: 'for' is a KEYWORD of language but in some cases becomes a simple string to print in output (as when it follows in any order, the echo command).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see how you could go about doing this, is define an `Echo` rule in your lexer grammar that matches the characters `echo` followed by all other characters except `\r` and `\n`:

```
Echo
  :  'echo' ~('\r' | '\n')+
  ;
```

and make sure that rule is ***before*** the rule that matches identifiers and keywords (like `for`).

A quick demo of a possible  start would be:

```
grammar Test;

parse
  :  (echo | for)*
  ;

echo
  :  Echo (NewLine | EOF)
  ;

for 
  :  For Identifier In range NewLine
     Do NewLine
     echo
     Done (NewLine | EOF)
  ;

range
  :  '{' Integer '..' Integer ('..' Integer)? '}'
  ;

Echo
  :  'echo' ~('\r' | '\n')+
  ;

For  : 'for';
In   : 'in';
Do   : 'do';
Done : 'done';

Identifier
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9')*
  ;

Integer
  :  '0'..'9'+
  ;

NewLine
  :  '\r' '\n'
  |  '\n'
  |  '\r'
  ;

Space
  :  (' ' | '\t') {skip();}
  ;
```

If you'd parse the input:

```
echo for print example
for i in {0..10..2}
do
  echo "Welcome $i times"
done
echo the end for now!
```

with it, it would look like:

[alt text http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/5713/grammar.png](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/5713/grammar.png)

(I had to rotate the image a bit, otherwise it wouldn't be visible at all!)

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to use a semantic predicate to only take that lexer rule when it really is the `for` keyword.

Details are available on the [keywords as identifiers](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1741) page on the ANTLR wiki.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's pretty easy, most grammars use something like this:

```
TOKEN_REF
    :   'A'..'Z' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*
    ;
```

So when referring to a print statement you would do something like:

```
'print' (TOKEN_REF)*
```

And with a for statement you just explicity state 'for' such as:

```
'for' INT 'in' SOMETHING
```

Comment: No, I can't see that working. Let's say there is a `FOR` rule that looks like `FOR : 'for';`. Now if `FOR` gets tokenized before `TOKEN_REF`, then `TOKEN_REF` could never contain the characters `for` (and therefore `'print' (TOKEN_REF)*` can never contain `'for'`). But if `TOKEN_REF` gets tokenized before `FOR`, then the `FOR` rule will never be matched since `TOKEN_REF` will always match `for`. Did you try what you suggested? If so, did it work and would you care to post it? Thanks.